# Aggregation operation failed: localhost:27017: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am using mongoDB library from [link](https://github.com/intekhabrizvi/Codeigniter-mongo-library/blob/master/application/libraries/Mongo_db.php) with CI. I want to join two tables so I found it can be done using **lookup**

I am using below code for it

```
$this->load->library('mongo_db',array('activate' => 'default'),'mongo_db');

$res = $this->mongo_db->aggregate(
    'firstTable',
    array(

        '$lookup' => array(
        'from' => 'secondTable',
        'localField' => '_id',
        'foreignField' => 'foreignKey',
        'as' => 'user',                 
    )               
));

echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);
```

It gives error as

```
Aggregation operation failed: localhost:27017: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
```

How I can add cursor in this case

**I checked other similar answers but not getting how I can add cursor in this case**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43860374/8369507

Comment: @MohitKumarBordia : function aggregateCursor is not in library I am using

Comment: Try with below mentioned link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43851216/8369507

Comment: https://github.com/vesparny/cimongo-codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/master/libraries/cimongo/Cimongo.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use the another codeigniter library from [here](https://github.com/verkhoumov/codeigniter-mongodb-library/wiki). This library allows you to pass the aggregation options.

You can try below aggregation query. Set batchsize to 0 to have mongodb use server's default batch size.

```
$res = $this->mongo_db->aggregate(
    'firstTable',
     array(
       '$lookup' => array(
         'from' => 'secondTable',
         'localField' => '_id',
         'foreignField' => 'foreignKey',
        'as' => 'user',                 
       )                
     ),
     array('cursor' => array('batchSize' => 0))
);
```

More information [here](https://github.com/verkhoumov/codeigniter-mongodb-library/wiki/Commands-and-Aggregation-queries)

Comment: did you get a chance to try my answer ? 
Unfortunately the library you use don't have the argument to send option which is required from 3.4 version.

Comment: Not getting drivers used in library   "use MongoDB\Driver\{Query, Manager, Command, BulkWrite, Cursor, WriteConcern, WriteResult, ReadPreference, ReadConcern};"

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/

> Specify a document that contains options that control the creation of
>   the cursor object.
>
> Changed in version 3.6: MongoDB 3.6 removes the use of aggregate
>   command without the cursor option unless the command includes the
>   explain option. Unless you include the explain option, you must
>   specify the cursor option.
>
> To indicate a cursor with the default batch size, specify cursor: {}.
>
> To indicate a cursor with a non-default batch size, use cursor: {
>   batchSize:  }.